# How to import mail from Outlook to an IBM Notes document

Tags: outlook, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, inbox, ibm-domino

I have a customer who is switching Mail client from IBM Notes to Outlook.

The customer is still using Notes and have currently an application with a button that bring up a dialog where the user can import mail from the users IBM Notes mail inbox into a Notesdocument in the application

I now need to rewrite this code so that the dialog instead show the inbox from Outlook and import the selected outlook mail into the notesdocument

how can I do that?

Thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Exchange Web Services API to talk to Exchange. Here’s an old blog post of mine with examples: http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2011/09/integrating-a-lotus-notes-application-with-exchange.html